# How to verify and get response of all href="javascript:void(0)" through out website not only single page using selenium

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver

```
a class="linkEffect" href="javascript:void(0)"
```

Note : I can get reference link by findelements property but somehow when I click on it than on redirect page I loss base as well I am not able get HTTP response like 200 - 404 - 500.

Please let me know if you have any perfect solution for it.

With below code I just get Main link which is not href="javascript:void(0)" also I get only for One Page i.e. which I mention URL. I want to find throughout website. Below is general code which is not working properly as per my requirement

Comment: where is your code?

Comment: I am using https://www.seleniumeasy.com/selenium-tutorials/how-to-find-broken-links-using-webdriver-java this code.

Comment: https://90pluswine.com/ from this website I want to fetch all link and verify response which is given as href="javascript:void(0)"